# Binary Data injected in String

Tags: c++, string, named-pipes

I've got a block of C++ code that reads text from a named pipe. The relevant section is:

```
char s[256];
int num, fd;
string command;

command.erase(); //Clear the command string
cout << "Command0:" << endl << command << endl;
fd = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY); //Will block until a writer connects
do {
    if ((num = read(fd, s, 255)) == -1)
        perror("read");
    else {
        cout << "Command1:" << endl << command << endl;
        s[num+1] = '\0';
        cout << "Command2:" << endl << command << endl;
        //printf("read %d bytes: \"%s\"\n", num, s);
        command += s;
    }
} while (num > 0);
cout << "Command:" << endl << command << endl;
```

The "commandX" printfs are some debug code that I'll reference the output of in a second. The chunks of text that get read into s print just fine, but after it null-terminates the char array, I end up with binary junk in the "command" string:

```
Command0:

Command1:

Command2:
```

Other than that, everything appears to work fine. The char[] concatenates onto the command string correctly, so I end up with the complete string, just with some extra binary on the front end. Am I having a weird array out of bounds problem here that is writing to command's memory?

Comment: I think the null termination should go at index `num` and not `num+1`. If you have read `num` characters, then they are filled from `0` to `num-1` indexes.

Comment: It should be s[num] = '\0' not num+1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the below condition,

```
if ((num = read(fd, s, 255))
```

If `num = 255;` then

```
s[num+1] = '\0';
```

will set `s[256] = 0;` which is out of range for `s[0] to s[255]`.

Comment: Man, that was a dumb one. I remembered to read one fewer character to leave room, then went and ran off the end anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
    command += s;
```

Have you tried:

```
command.append(s, num);
```

?

This way you don't need to bother with null-terminating etc, just add the read characters.